# flask jinja2 template renders question marks instead of utf-8 characters

Tags: templates, unicode, utf-8, flask, jinja2

I'm working on a flask project. The database has been set to `UTF8_bin`, but after selecting data from database at the time of rendering the html page, it returns question marks insted of `persian alphabet letters` in `{{ }}`. I also have put `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the html file.

In html page:

```
{% for each in menue %}
    <li>{{ each.txt }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And the output is:

> ?????????

What is the problem? Only selected utf8 data from database cannot be rendered in `{{ }}`. Other persian letters in the html page have been rendered well.